# React - Getting collection from Firebase and updating state to render a child component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

pardon my ignorance but I'm still in the early days of learning react and firebase.

I'm trying to implement some functionality where a user can click on a category, then they will be navigated to this ViewItemPage component, where I'm attempting to get a collection from firebase based on the category that the user clicked. Once the collection has been retrieved I'm trying to select a random item from the collection and use that data to render another child component.

I'm assuming this is either a lifecycle issue and/or I'm using react hooks completely incorrectly, but I've been stuck trying to figure this out way too long

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { AnotherComponent } from './AnotherComponent ';

export function ViewItemPage() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { category } = state;
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();

  const itemsRef = collection(db, 'items');
  const getItems = async (e) => {
    try {
      const q = query(itemsRef, where('category', '==', category));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setItems({ data: doc.data() });
      });

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  const getRandomItem = () => {
    const randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    setSelectedItem(randomItem);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [loading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRandomItem();
    // eslint-disable-next-line      
  });
return <AnotherComponent category={category} item={selectedItem} />;
}
```

in the above example I'm attempting to use a forEach loop to  update the state, but I've also tried mapping the response:

```
setItems(
         querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
       );
```

and it has the same result, the child component seems to be passed and empty object, and throws an error when attempting to read any of the items properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more learning, trial and error, and refactoring it seems to be working as I intended it to now. Here's the code in case someone else might find it useful

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';
import { AnotherComponent} from './AnotherComponent ';

export function ViewItemPage() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { category } = state;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [randomItem, setRandomItem] = useState();
  let itemArray = [];

  const getItems = async () => {
    try {
      const q = query(
        collection(db, 'items'),
        where('category', '==', category)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        itemArray = [...itemArray, doc.data()];
      });

      setRandomItem(
        itemArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * itemArray.length)]
      );
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [loading]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: '100vh',
        }}
      >
        Loading the data
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <AnotherComponent item={randomItem} />;
}
```